# DB Connections in session variables fails after migrating from Win2k3 to Win2012 R2

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, odbc, iis-6, iis-8.5

I currently have a Classic ASP website running on IIS6, and everything works well. "Include" file is used to open a db connection.  The db connection is then stored in a session variable.

Here's a snippet of our Include "dbinclude.asp" file:

```
<%
Set CN_sql = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
CN_sql.ConnectionString="DSN=sqldb;UID=testuid;PWD=testpwd;Server=testdb;Database=mydatabase"
CN_sql.Open
Session("Connection_sql") = CN_sql
%>
```

In the classic asp pages, we use the following code to connect to the DB to pull data:

```
<html>
<head>
<!--#include file="./dbinclude.asp"-->
</head>
</body>
<%
    set ds = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    CN_sql = Session("Connection_sql")
    ds.ActiveConnection = CN_sql
    ds.CursorType = 0

    SQL = "select * "
    SQL = SQL & " from users "

    ds.Source = SQL
    ds.Open

    IF ds.EOF then
        response.write("SQL EOF.  NO data found.<br/>")
    ELSE
        ds.MoveFirst
        while not ds.EOF
            response.write(ds.fields("user_name") & " <br/> ")
            ds.MoveNext
        wend    
    End If
%>
</body>
</html>
```

In IIS6, this code runs fine for all pages.  However, when testing in IIS8.5 (Win2012R2, and also IIS7,Win7), I get this error message:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The line number where the error points to is this line:

```
 ds.ActiveConnection = CN_sql
```

The Application Pool in IIS 8.5 is set to .NET v2, allows 32-bit application, Classic Pipeline.  I've tried various combination of the application pool (changing to different .NET version, allow/disallow 32-bit application, Classic/Integrated pipeline, changed the Identity, tried different Session States).

**In IIS 8.5, if I comment out the following line in the code:

    `CN_sql = Session("Connection_sql")`

it will resolve the issue.**  However, since we have a large number of pages, rewriting **and testing** is not feasible at the moment.

Is there something in Windows 2012 that blocks you from storing an open database connection in a session variable?  I know it's not efficient, but rewriting will be a big undertaking at this time.

Comment: Not positive, but shouldn't you be using `set` when assigning variables to objects? As in `set CN_sql = Session("Connection_sql")`, and you might also need `set` in some of the other assignments.

Comment: Why not store it in an application variable in global.asa.  You should then be able to run a global replacement to replace `Session("Connection_sql")` with `Application("Connection_sql")` Even on a large site this should only take a few seconds. A session variable seems a strange place to store a conn string

Comment: @John: I still will have to open the connection, and I think that's what blowing it up, but I'll give it a shot. @Keith: `set` is not needed.  I did try but it generated another error.

Comment: I don't see why that should be a problem

Comment: It also might be worth trying a different conn string - take a look at the OLEDB providers here - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I tried with `Application("Connection_sql")` in global.asa, and it returned the same error.  I'll check out the OLEDB providers.  Thanks!

Comment: If the Windows Server 2012 is 64-bit you will need to make sure that the DSN `sqldb` is re-created in the 32 bit ODBC Data Source Administrator, which is located - `%WinDir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. If you use the default `odbcad32.exe` you will register the DSN in the 64 bit ODBC environment, which your 32 bit App Pool will not see. **Edit:** - Sorry didn't notice the answer.

Comment: Yep, I used the 32-bit ODBC to create the DSN.  If I comment out the `CN_sql = Session("Connection_sql")`, the code will run, but that means I would have to go in to every file to do that and it is not feasible at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like, on the new server, you didn't re-create the DSN ([Data Source Name](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/966849)) specified in the connection string:

```
DSN=sqldb
```

If your application is running in a 32 bit worker process/app pool on 64 bit Windows then recreate it using:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

Otherwise recreate using:

```
C:\Windows\system32\odbcad32.exe
```

This KB article is also quite use when working with DSN's on 64 bit systems:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942976

Comment: DSN was created using 32-bit ODBC Data Source Admin.  I refer to it in the ConnectionString.  If I comment out the `CN_sql = Session("Connection_sql")`, the code will run.